# input syntax in paraview python shell

Tags: python, scripting, paraview

I currently am trying to use

```
paraview.simple.Histogram(Input, params)
```

as

```
paraview.simple.Histogram(q, BinCount = 30)
```

in the shell where q is a variable data set from my "out.e" ExodusII file. I'm getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'q' is not defined
```

I've tried to search the literature on python shell scripting in Paraview but it seems to be eluding me. I know this is a quick fix. Thanks

Comment: what is q and where is it defined?

Comment: It is a variable that is defined in my solution file out.e. It has a unique value in each of the nodes.

Comment: post the code preceding where you call `paraview.simple.Histogram(q, BinCount = 30) `

Comment: There is none. I guess I'm confused on how to define my variable(which exists in the solution dataset) as Input for the shell syntax.

Comment: so p is in a file `out.e`? How does that file interact with your  program?

Comment: It is loaded already in what is known as the pipeline browser. I can manually create my histogram by just point and click but I need to automate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to answer this problem using the following.

```
outset = Reader(FileName=['/dir/out.e'])
```

and for the Histogram

```
histogram1_1 = Histogram(Input=outset)
    histogram1_1.SelectInputArray = ['CELLS', 'q']
    histogram1_1.BinCount = 30
```

Note for anyone who comes into this issue, the TRACE option in the Python Shell will build a script for you when you do anything in the GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
Histogram(SelectInputArray="q", BinCount=30)
```

This assumes you currently have the reader as the *active* object in the **Pipeline** browser.

Comment: Ah, I think we are getting close! Let's say I read the Exodus object into the Pipeline with the command reader = ExodusIIReader(FileName = 'out.e'). How is q related to reader? q is an ElementVariable. In other words, what is the command to call q from my data object?

Comment: Have you tried using the Tracing capabilities? The Python Trace can help you come up with the Python commmands to use to setup the reader property to make sure that "q" is loaded from the data file.

Comment: I'm using reader = ExodusIIReader(FileName='out.e') and then using histogram = Histogram(SelectInputArray = reader.ElementVariables[0],BinCount = 0) but it is NOT updating the histogram pipeline object. Is this a bug? I'm currently combing the paraview pipermail for this problem but it seems to be eluding me. This is assuming I have the reader as active correct? I also tried to use Show(reader) before my Histogram() command to ensure this. Thanks

Comment: I'm going to post this as completed.